# How to set server-side cookie to iframe on iphone or ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iframe, browser, setcookie

I developed web game. But while integrating this game inside iframe in other websites, setting server-side cookie not working on only iphone or ipad devices.
When it launch game url, the sever set cookies using response header. But it is not working.

```
res.cookie("token", token, {
  path: "/",
  httpOnly: true,
  overwrite: true,
  sameSite: "None",
  secure: true,
});
res.cookie("lang", user.lang, {
  overwrite: true,
  sameSite: "None",
  secure: true,
});
res.cookie("locale", locale[user.lang], {
  overwrite: true,
  sameSite: "None",
  secure: true,
});
```

All the browsers are working on all devices except iphone or iframe.
Even if the device is iphone or ipad, they are working when I do not use iframe.
How to fix it?